# Prove that $f(x)$ is not continuous at any point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions, continuity

Let $f:R->R$ be defined by 
\begin{equation} f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} [x] & \text{if} & x \quad \text{rational}\\\\ [x]+3 & \text{if} &x \quad \text{irrational}\\ \end{array} \right. \end{equation}
where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. 
(Example: $[0.5]=0$, $[2]=2$, $[-0.2]=-1$)

Prove that $f(x)$ is not continuous at any point. I know I have to use $Sn$ as a sequence and $C$ as an integer. The sequence I'm using is $Sn=C+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Case 1 will be when $C$ is an integer and case 2 will be when $C$ is an arbitrary point. So far I have:
Let $Sn$ be a sequence such that $lim Sn=C$ where $C$ is not an integer. Then $lim[Sn]=[C]$.

Comment: If you want to use sequences, you either have to use two sequences, where one consists of rational numbers and the other of irrational numbers, or you have to use one sequence that alternates between rational and irrational numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If your function is continous then:

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0 : |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon$ must be true.

Let $\epsilon = \frac 12$

for all $x,$ and all $\delta>0$ there is both an irrational and a rational value for $a\in (x, x+\delta)$

And for one of those $|f(x) - f(a)| > \epsilon$

$f(x)$ is not continuous at any $x.$

Comment: We can't use this to prove it. The sequence Sn has to be used for 2 different cases.

Comment: Is this explicit in the instructions?  The sequence you have suggested will not work.  If $C$ is rational  all $S_n$ will be rational and you won't find lack of convergence.  You are going to need  a sequence that touches both rational and irrational values.

Comment: We were given hints to complete the proof, including that specific sequence.

Comment: @pmk1007 This is the standard way of proving this result. Perhaps your lecturer is asking you something subtly different?

Comment: @DougM Would this sequence above work for when $C$ is irrational?

Comment: I just want to state again that that [x] is the greatest integer less than or equal to x. So it x will always be in Z.

Comment: $x$ is not in $\mathbb Z$, $f(x)$ is in $\mathbb Z.$  Nonetheless, for any $x,$ there is an $a$ in the neighborhood of $x$ that maps to a different integer.

Comment: If $C=1$ for example, then $lim Sn=1$. $[Sn]=0,1,0,1,....$ so $lim [Sn]$ DNE, using that sequence. So why can't this sequence be used when $C$ is rational?

Comment: Suppose $C = 0.5.  S_3 = \frac 16, S_4 = \frac 34, S_3 = \frac 3{10}, S_6 = \frac 23\cdots f(S_3) = f(S_4) = f(S_5) = f(S_n) = 0$  Suppose $C = \sqrt 2, S_n$ is irrational,  for all $n\ge2, f(S_n) = 4$

Comment: But since $C$ is rational, then $[C]=[0.5]=0$, I think.

Comment: Yes... as is $\lfloor S_n \rfloor$ and how are you going to prove dis-continuity?

Comment: Because then $[Sn]:-1,0,-1,0,...$. It doesn't converge so it is not continuous. Ex: $[S1]=[0]+[-1]=-$, $[S2]=[0]+[-1^2/2]=[1/2]=0$, $[S3]=[0]+[-1^3/3]=[-1/3]=-1$

Comment: Not with the way you have defined $S_n$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something that involves a sequence $S_n \rightarrow C$, for which it is not the case that the sequence $f(S_n) \rightarrow f(C)$. In this case, I reckon that the two situations to deal with are $C \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $C \not\in \mathbb{Q}$. The result then follows from the following **fact**: for every real number $C$, there is both a sequence of *only* rational numbers that converges to $C$, and a sequence of *only* irrational numbers that converges to $C$. For example, if $C \in \mathbb{Q}$, then the constant sequence $C, C, C, \ldots \rightarrow C$ consists of all rational elements, whereas the sequence $C + \sqrt{2}/n \rightarrow C$ consists of all irrational elements. If $f$ were continuous, then we would need $f(C)$ to be *both* $[C]$ and $[C] + 3$, a contradiction. I will leave the case of $C \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ to you.